# Odd decimal type behavior for ToString(IFormatProvider)

Tags: c#, iformatprovider

```
var numberFormat = new NumberFormatInfo();
numberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
numberFormat.NumberDecimalDigits = 2;

decimal a = 10.00M;
decimal b = 10M;

Console.WriteLine(a.ToString(numberFormat));
Console.WriteLine(b.ToString(numberFormat));
Console.WriteLine(a == b ? "True": "False");
```

In console:
    10.00
    10
    True

Why is it different? More important, how do I call ToString() to ensure same output no matter how a variable is initialized?

Comment: What output are you expecting? 10, 10, true ?

Comment: Well, I was kind of hoping for 10.00 10.00 true, but at least it would be clear that numberFormat was wrong if it was 10 10 true. This just confused me (as my actual code isn't so simple, it took some time to figure out why was number format ok for one decimal but wrong for another)

Comment: Side note: bool implements a usable `ToString`, so `Console.WriteLine(a == b);` will print the same thing as in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `NumberDecimalDigits` property is used with the `"F"` and `"N"` standard format strings, not the `ToString` method called without a format string.

You can use:

```
Console.WriteLine(a.ToString("N", numberFormat));
```

Answer (score 4):

The question of how to make it output consistently has been answered, but here is why they output differently in the first place:

A `decimal` value contains, internally, fields for a scale and a coefficient. In the case of `10M`, the value encoded has a coefficient of 10 and a scale of 0:

```
10M = 10 * 10^0
```

In the case of `10.00M`, the value encoded has a coefficient of 1000 and a scale of 2:

```
10.00M = 1000 * 10^(-2)
```

You can sort of see this by inspecting the values in-memory:

```
unsafe
{
    fixed (decimal* array = new decimal[2])
    {
        array[0] = 10M;
        array[1] = 10.00M;
        byte* ptr = (byte*)array;

        Console.Write("10M:    ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
            Console.Write(ptr[i].ToString("X2") + " ");

        Console.WriteLine("");

        Console.Write("10.00M: ");
        for (int i = 16; i < 32; i++)
            Console.Write(ptr[i].ToString("X2") + " ");
    }
}
```

Outputs

```
10M:    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 0A 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
10.00M: 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 E8 03 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

(0xA is 10 in hex, and 0x3E8 is 1000 in hex)

This behaviour is outlined in section 2.4.4.3 of the C# spec:

> A real literal suffixed by M or m is of type decimal. For example, the literals 1m, 1.5m, 1e10m, and 123.456M are all of type decimal. This literal is converted to a decimal value by taking the exact value, and, if necessary, rounding to the nearest representable value using banker's rounding (§4.1.7). **Any scale apparent in the literal is preserved unless the value is rounded or the value is zero (in which latter case the sign and scale will be 0). Hence, the literal 2.900m will be parsed to form the decimal with sign 0, coefficient 2900, and scale 3.**

Comment: Interesting, thank you for the effort. Yet, this explains how they are different, not why ToString cares about how they're represented in memory. Shouldn't ToString on primitive types offer some kind guarantee that provided logically equal inputs it would return same output? Or is this by design (ToString's behaviour, not decimal's)?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.00}", a)); 
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.00}", b));
```

The output will have always 2 decimal cases. More examples here:

http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-double/

Comment: But it won't always have a period as decimal separator.

Comment: It doesn't matter it the number has a decimal separator or not, the output will have always 2 decimal cases. if you try `Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:0.00}", 10M));` you'll see that the output is `10.00`

Comment: You are missing the point. The OP specified in the number format that the decimal separator should be a period. If you are not using the number format, the decimal separator will instead be the one specificed in the default culture. When I try that code, I see that the output is `10,00`.