# Decimal "ToString" returns extra decimal values

Tags: .net, decimal, tostring

I have decimal type variables which, depending on how it is set, yields a different value on a ToString() method. How can I make a ToString() always return the string with the trailing zeros after the decimal point removed? Wanting a good numeric type answer, not string manipulation after the fact.

Using an Immediate Windows (cause it's just easy)

> ?(5.00D).ToString() & " " & CType("5",Decimal).ToString() & " " & CType("5.00",Decimal).ToString()

yields this:

> 5 5 5.00

So these are all decimal types, but depending how one is set, it somehow gives a different precision on ToString().

Per MS documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd(v=vs.110).aspx), a blank .ToString() is the same as .ToString("G"), which does seem to be true. Per MS documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx#GFormatString), formatting "G" or "g" is "general", and with general the "result contains a decimal point if required, and trailing zeros after the decimal point are omitted."

Yes, I know that I can format to *always* give the same precision, but I want it to give the "normal" precision, simply not writing superfluous zeros at the end after the decimal point, the same an we don't normally prepend numbers with zeros.

I'm using VB .Net 2008, but I think this holds in all versions to date. This question [Odd decimal type behavior for ToString(IFormatProvider)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13810922/odd-decimal-type-behavior-for-tostringiformatprovider) is a very similar problem, but mine is a bit worse, so don't cite that question please.

Comment: The `G` format specifier has special behavior if the number is a `decimal`. You didn't mention that in your question so in case you did not notice... From MSDN: "However, if the number is a Decimal and the precision specifier is omitted, fixed-point notation is always used and trailing zeros are preserved."

Comment: The vb.net compiler drops the ball on the 5.00D version.  It initializes the variable with the Decimal(Int64) constructor and thus can't keep track of the number of digits in the fraction.  I think it is a defect but they are not going to fix it, this has been this way for too long.  Actually trying to type this into a program with the editor instead of using the Immediate window gives insight.