# Convert.ToString(Decimal, IFormatProvider) or String.Format

Tags: c#, cultureinfo, iformatprovider

i've seen the question [Odd decimal type behavior for ToString(IFormatProvider)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13810922/odd-decimal-type-behavior-for-tostringiformatprovider)

this is my test code

```
// Define an array of numbers to display.
double[] numbers = { -1.5345e16, -123.4321, 19092.123, 1.1734231911290e16 };
// Define the culture names used to display them.
string[] cultureNames = { "en-US", "fr-FR", "ja-JP", "ru-RU" };

foreach (double number in numbers)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0}:", Convert.ToString(number,
                              System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    foreach (string cultureName in cultureNames)
    {
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureName);
        culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSizes = new int[] {2,2,3};
        culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalDigits = 5;
        Console.WriteLine(".ToString          {0}: {1,20}",
                          culture.Name, number.ToString("N", culture));
        Console.WriteLine("Convert.ToString   {0}: {1,20}", 
            culture.Name, Convert.ToString(number, culture));
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

and the sample result is as below:

why is Convert.ToString not applying the format?

[image]

This is with Win7 Prof/VS2010+SP1Rel (10.0.40219.1)

Comment: I know the format specifier "N" is not there in the `Convert.ToString`. But I do not want to depend on the `.ToString()` as my values may have nulls causing exception. 

And I do not want to got the `string.Format` way

Comment: That comment is very unclear. It would really help if you'd give more detail about the *real* problem you're facing, so we could help you use `double.ToString` or `string.Format` effectively.

Comment: "my values may have nulls"  What **exact** type are your values, anyway?

Comment: fetched from the database, money, int and long

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the documentation for [`Convert.ToString(double, IFormatProvider)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131010.aspx):

> This implementation is identical to Double.ToString(IFormatProvider)

... which is then [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/shxtf045.aspx) as:

> The ToString(IFormatProvider) method formats a Double value in the default ("G", or general) format of a specified culture.

When you call `ToString`, you're passing in `N` - if you pass in `G` instead, you'll get the same results as `Convert.ToString`.

The [`G` format specifier documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#GFormatString) states:

> The result string is affected by the formatting information of the current NumberFormatInfo object. The following table lists the NumberFormatInfo properties that control the formatting of the result string.

... and lists `NegativeSign`, `NumberDecimalSeparator`, `PositiveSign`. Your code doesn't set any of those properties, which is why it's not making a difference. If you write:

```
culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = "#"
```

for example, then that *will* affect the output of `Convert.ToString`.

Comment: do you mean even if i do not want to modify, if I change one of the properties like  numberdecimalseperator, then then the code will use my customised culture object? and not in the other case.

What i was trying to achieve was alter only the needed properties of   my local CultureInfo object.

Comment: @eyesice: I didn't really follow your comment, but yes, if you call `Convert.ToString(double, IFormatProvider)` it will use those three properties - but no other ones.

Comment: let me try to explain.

my app needs specific formats for currency and decimals. say `CurrencyDecimalDigits = 3` and `NumberDecimalDigits = 3` and no grouping for decimals (which are generally quantities).

I'm trying to generalise by building a customised cultureinfo object, set this to current UI & app thread. Thereby, my cast should pick the formatting specified. 

This is an existing repo an I do not have the luxury to modify the entire code.

Comment: @eyesice: And that's all fine - but you shouldn't expect `Convert.ToString` to use all of that, because that uses the `G` format. Basically, you need to find a way to use `string.Format` appropriately. I suggest you ask a *new* question explaining the reasons you've had problems with `string.Format`, and we can try to fix the problem there. Fundamentally, the answer to the question you've asked here is "Everything is behaving as documented."

Comment: I believe we are not on the same page. I agree that "N" is the format for number and "G" is for general. I have to use "N" and not "D" for decimal 'cause the `.ToString("D"` raises an FormatException. So the closest is "N" right? And for `Convert.ToString`, the value is already a decimal (in both cases) and i'm asking for the string representation as-per the culture object. And if i do not add an extra  formatting qualifier (which again is not supported in Convert) the why the effort?

Comment: for any interested in teh format qualifiers. look here. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @eyesice: There's no notion of "the string representation" - there are different string representations depending on what format you ask for. Basically it sounds like you want to use the "N" format, which means you can't use `Convert.ToString`. It's not clear what you mean by "why the effort" - what effort? Basically, you've got down the wrong path here by trying `Convert.ToString`. Back out of that, and ask a new question about how to use `string.Format` appropriately.

Comment: using "G" or removing the formatter, keeping the cultureinfo object produce identical result.  The point is can we depend on CultureInfo and typecast to provide a formatted value other than by using `string.format` explicitly.... my experience points to a big "NO"

Comment: @eyesice: Your comment doesn't have nearly enough context for me to understand what you mean. (You clearly know what code you're talking about, but I don't.) Calling `Convert.ToString` *isn't* a cast... but yes, if you want to format in a specific way, you should use `string.Format` or cast to `IFormattable` and call `ToString` directly.